# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I tried this but it says this error:

> cannot resolve symbol `i`

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    if (!incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Incident i = incidentQueue.element();
        incidentQueue.remove();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `i` to be when `incidentQueue` is empty?

Comment: Because you are trying to use variable `i` out of its scope.

Comment: The variable `i` is only in scope inside the `if` block. It doesn't exist anymore when you try to return it. What class is `incidentQueue`?

Comment: You can not use a variable outside of the scope it was declared in. You create `i` inside the `if`, so it will be destroyed as soon as the `if` ends. You have to create `i` before the `if`. For example as `Incident i = null;` and then assign it inside the `if` as `i = ...`. Then you can use it outside. But you need to be aware that it is `null` if it did not enter the `if`, you should handle this case.

Comment: So do I need the i? And how to return the Incident?

Comment: And if I change the return type from Incident to void. Would the remove method still return the Incident? incidentQueue is a Queue.

Comment: It is impossible to return a value in a `void` method. `void`  literally means _"I do not return anything"_.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

You can not use a variable **outside** of the scope it was declared in.

You create `i` **inside** the `if`, so it will be destroyed as soon as the `if` ends. You have to create `i` **before** the `if`. For example:

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    Incident i = null;
    if (!incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        i = incidentQueue.element();
        incidentQueue.remove();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Then you can use it outside, as you see.

---

### Handle empty case

But you need to be aware that it is `null` if it did not enter the `if`, you should handle this case:

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    Incident i = null;
    if (!incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        i = incidentQueue.element();
        incidentQueue.remove();
    }

    if (i == null) {
        // TODO Handle this case ...
    }

    return i;
}
```

Note that you can also directly return from **inside** your `if`, there is no need to do it outside:

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    if (!incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Incident i = incidentQueue.element();
        incidentQueue.remove();
        return i;
    }

    // TODO Handle this case ...
}
```

Or, slightly rewritten in an early-return fashion (preferred style):

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    if (incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        // TODO Handle this case ...
    }

    Incident i = incidentQueue.element();
    incidentQueue.remove();
    return i;
}
```

---

### Poll

Note that there is a commonly used name for a method in a queue that removes and gives back the first value, `poll`. And if your queue happens to be a queue from the Java library, as opposed to a custom class, it also already has such a method.

See the documentation of [Queue#poll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll()):

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

So instead of creating this method, you could just do

```
Incident head = incidentQueue.poll();
// instead of
Incident head = incidentQueue.getNextIncident();
```

---

### Optional

Let me propose you a modern way of handling the case that you can not return a value because the queue is empty.

The old-style way is to return `null`, but this has many drawbacks. Since Java 8, we have `Optional` which was created exactly for that (see its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html)).

```
public Optional<Incident> poll() {
    if (incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    Incident head = incidentQueue.element();
    incidentQueue.remove();
    return Optional.of(head);
}
```

---

### Note

I would also suggest to rename the incident variable to `incident` or `head` instead of `i`. Do not abbreviate variable names, except they are commonly known (like `http`) or it is common pattern (like `i`, `j`, `k` for loops or `a`, `b` for math operations). `i` would only be confusing here, as it is usually used as index variable `int i` in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible for the method to do nothing if the Queue is empty?

Comment: You have to return _something_ then. Old-fashion would be to return `null`. Then the user can check this case `if (foo == null) ...`. Modern style would be to use `Optional`. That's exactly what it was made for. So your return type is `Optional<Incident>` and you return `Optional.empty()` then. And if there is a value, you return `Optional.of(incident)`. Then the user can check using `result.isEmpty()` and similar methods. (Updated the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You're duplicating existing `Queue` functionality for nothing. Your code (if it worked) is equivalent to

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    return incidentQueue.poll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `i` inside an `if` condition, so the compiler are saying that in the line `return i;` it may not know what is `i`.

You must declare it before the `if`:

```
public Incident getNextIncident() {
    Incident i = null;
    if (!incidentQueue.isEmpty()) {
        i = incidentQueue.element();
        incidentQueue.remove();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: must be `Incident i = null;`, if not, compiler will complain

Answer (score 0):

It should be just a small issue. You have declared the Incident object inside the if block. Meaning it only stays there. After you reach the `return i;` part, it basically doesn't exist. You have to declare the `Incident i` outside the if block.